# get values from errors array Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to get the message from the errors array for a field.

Example for the password field:

```
   @user.errors.select{|key,msg| key == :password}
```

This produces:

```
{:password=>["Your password and confirmation are not the same"]}
```

What I want is a way to just get the message for the field.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `@user.errors[:password]`

Alternatively you can use one of the [following methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000744)

> hsh.values → array
>   Returns a new array populated with the values from hsh. See also Hash#keys.

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => 300 }
h.values   #=> [100, 200, 300]
```

> hsh.values_at(key, ...) → array
>   Return an array containing the values associated with the given keys. Also see Hash.select.

```
h = { "cat" => "feline", "dog" => "canine", "cow" => "bovine" }
h.values_at("cow", "cat")  #=> ["bovine", "feline"]
```

**edit:**

Using the values method you could do this

```
@user.errors.select{|key,msg| key == :password}.values.first
```

It depends on what you need. Keep in mind that any `errors` value is an array itself because a form field could have more than one error. Try it yourself with rails console

```
> pry
pry(main)> {:password=>["Your password and confirmation are not the same"]}
=> {:password=>["Your password and confirmation are not the same"]}
pry(main)> {:password=>["Your password and confirmation are not the same"]}.values
=> [["Your password and confirmation are not the same"]]
pry(main)> {:password=>["Your password and confirmation are not the same"]}.values.first
=> ["Your password and confirmation are not the same"]
pry(main)> {:password=>["Your password and confirmation are not the same"]}.values.first.first
=> "Your password and confirmation are not the same"
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio. Is there anyway to do this in the block above. As in @user.errors.select{|key,msg| key == :password, msg} or something along those lines?

Comment: @chell Updated my answer to reflect your comment content. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks Fabio it works as you have posted so clearly. Thanks very much I will use it. Great.